# Is there a library and header to use to access EWMH/NetWM functions?

Tags: linux, api, ewmh

I need to get similar information on the current windows and virtual desktops as that provided by the command-line app `wmctrl`. I s there some (C/C++) API header & lib-files that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the source code of [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl) and study it. If you are making some free software with the same or compatible GPLv2 license you could take some code from it.

There is only one source file `main.c` and it seems to do ordinary Xlib calls, notably [XGetWindowProperty](http://www.xfree86.org/current/XChangeProperty.3.html) calls wrapped in `get_property`

I'm very surprised you asked the question here. With free software, it is so much simpler and quicker to download the source code and study it.

Comment: I'm a KISS disciple, I ALWAYS first look for the easiest & simplest way to do something, in this case an API-call, but failing that I'll have to go to wmctrl's source, yes. I have browsed open-source app's sources before & some of those were real spaghetti-monsters, for instance I liked the old KDE3 dictionary applet, so I'm going through it's source & is rewriting it as a plain desktop app in beteen other projects. So don't be so surprised that I ask first ;)

Comment: Still, the quicker way to get the answer is to download and study source code, especially `wmctrl`'s one, which is only one C file of 1527 lines only! You've waited almost 9 hours to get an answer that you could have got in minutes (and I never heard of `wmctrl` before your question).

Comment: Okay, you're right; it will be very easy to modify into a header & code module that I can include & use in my project, thanks. Yes my project will eventually be GPL'ed and place in GitHub.

Comment: _"Just read the source of `wmctrl`"_ is very poor advise: `wmctrl` is **not** a reference implementation of the spec. And it is old, _very_ old. Last version was released in early 2005, so it predates the latest EWMH spec (v1.5, 2011) and even v1.3 from mid 2005. It is based on the obsolete v1.2 from 2002, so spec-wise `wmctrl` is terribly outdated.

Answer (score 2):

If it must be in C/C++, i think [`libxcb-wm`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxcb-wm) is the most prominent one: very mature, still actively developed, and from Freedesktop, the same organization that created the EWMH spec.

On Debian/Ubuntu you have the binary packages `libxcb-ewmh2` (run-time library) and `libxcb-ewmh-dev` (development headers), both from source package [`xcb-util-wm`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jammy/xcb-util-wm):

```bash
sudo apt install libxcb-ewmh-dev  # also pulls libxcb-ewmh2, as usual
```

And official [Documentation and Tutorial](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libxcb/tutorial/index.html) from Xorg

Comment: It only took 13 years! :) thx, now i can restore & continue my project